# Is there a best practice or best way to design form navigation?

Tags: forms

I'm creating a KYC form, and the question of navigation arose. I am unclear on what standards exist to make navigation like this easy and non-intrusive.

I have come up with two options. Which might be easier for the user?

[image]

Comment: It's two questions here: if there's a best practice standard and which of the two options you should go with.

Comment: It seems like there are a number of steps that the user needs to complete. Is this a linear process or can the user get to a specific step of the process?

Answer (score 1):

The standard that applies here is **Don't Repeat Yourself**. Users become confused when they see two ways to reach the next step in their task, and they don't know which one is "correct". The version on the left has redundant controls, so go with the version on the right. (Also, you wouldn't show a Back button in Step 1; use a different control to exit out of the form.)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the image on the right, but make the continue and back button the same sizes if you think the user will use both. Also, maybe change "continue" to "next" so that "back" and "next" take up the same character space